# google.maps.places Sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented google maps for the "places search-box" which works quite fine but sometimes the place is undefined...

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAE0jVybaY4jzT3irMM9g8THf3qGF6V9xE&callback=initMap&libraries=places"
async defer></script>
```

Search Boxes:

```
function initMap() {
    var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(48.210033, 16.363449), new google.maps.LatLng(48.210033, 16.363449));

    var options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        types: ['geocode']
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('searchInput'), options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (typeof place == "undefined") {
            window.alert("Not found!");
        }
        else{
            console.log(place);
            globalPlace = place;
        }
    });

    var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('searchInputAdd'), options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (typeof place == "undefined") {
            window.alert("Not found!");
        }
        else{
            console.log(place);
            globalPlaceAdd = place;
        }
    });
}
```

How can I fix that?

And another question, when I click on the autocomplete place it works but when I press enter the page reloads with post-params, can I disable that? That both ways work?

Comment: For your last point, the page reload because the enter submit a form. Just use a text input outside a form.

Comment: Is the place undefined when their suppose to be result or only when the search box have found nothing?

Comment: the place is undefined when their should be a result. I click on the autocompleted suggestion and than it is undefined

Comment: Is this behaviour happen randomly or all the time?

Comment: randomly, I am running a Web-Server in my network, most of the time when another person enters this Web-App he can't use one of two "search boxes" cause of this error

Comment: Can I access you application?

Comment: nope, it's a local webserver (gulp) just for the network users. Or how do you mean if you can access it?

Comment: I mean maybe you could create a jsfiddle that would reproduce the problem? If not, look in the network tab in DEV Tool to see if the response of the google service returned something when place is undefined.

Comment: I get the data which I should get. I found out when I test the second searchbox first and try than this error occurs but when I use the first one and after this the second one it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found your error. In your second listener, you are doing `autocomplete.getPlace()` instead of `autocomplete2.getPlace()`.

Try this instead:

```
var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('searchInputAdd'), options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete2.getPlace();
    if (typeof place == "undefined") {
        window.alert("Not found!");
    }
    else{
        console.log(place);
        globalPlaceAdd = place;
    }
});
```